# Is it possible disable SSL v3 in Codename One HTTPS requests?

Tags: codenameone

One of our customers did that question for us. 
They are facing some operational instability and they suppose the cause is related to SSL-V3 protocol.

Is it possible disable SSL-V3 protocol in "ConnectionRequest" class?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

We use the OS native SSL implementation by using the OS native HTTP API's e.g. `NSURL` in iOS and `URL` in Android/Java. The SSL layer is hidden.

You might be able to override this using native code by replacing the underlying protocols but it's pretty hairy stuff so I wouldn't recommend going there.

Comment: You don't need to replace the protocol, on iOS at least, it is possible to configure this programmatically.

Comment: I was referring to Android I have no idea how to do this in iOS. Either way you would need a native interface and some hacking to achieve this.